# Implementing slash in links like: example.com/parameter

Tags: php, hyperlink

I am trying to create links like `example.com/parameter` which leads to `example.com?id=parameter` or `example.com/index.php?id=parameter` using `php`
I searched alot about this and could not find a reference. all I need is the name of this technique so I can search for it.

Comment: It's called [url rewriting](https://www.google.com/search?q=url+rewriting). You do this through your webserver, not through PHP.

Comment: @Blender Technically it can also be done through PHP, with a single rewrite rule which directs everything to a routing file (in fact I use this approach on my own website). It's not as efficient, but it's more flexible.

Comment: @NicoBurns: That's still using the webserver to route requests to your main file, but yeah, you can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [mod_rewrite](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls) example. It's called URL rewriting or clean URLs.

Answer (score 1):

You use **URL Rewriting** like mod_rewrite, but the design pattern is called a `front controller`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `.htaccess` file to rewrite your URL's, there are loads of tutorial out there, take a look at this [article](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

Answer (score 0):

This technique is called **URL rewriting**. The most common way of doing this is using Apache's `mod_rewrite` module (you can Google that).

Comment: -1, at least have the courtesy to point the user at [the manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Perhaps I should have left a link, but in general I find the official documentation for this type of thing to be incredibly unhelpful unless you already know a fair amount about it and only want to look up a specific thing. Giving someone the term to google allows them to quickly find several clear and useful articles on the subject.